# sequence of solutions of a de

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continous and bounded and $u_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a sequence of solutions of the differential equation $y'=f(y)$. Show: If $u_n(0)$ is bounded, there exists a subsequence of $u_n$ which converges uniformly to a solution $u$ of the differential equation $y'=f(y)$.
My idea: Because $u_n(0)$ is bounded in $\mathbb R$, there exists a convergent subsequence $u_{n_k}(0)$. How can i show, that a subsequence of $u_n$ converges uniformly?

Comment: How does the function $h$ enter? Was it supposed to be called $f$?

Comment: it was my mistake. the function $h$ is $f$. So we dont have h:R-->R, we have f:R-->R

Comment: A good first step would be to say which solution the sequence converges to.

Comment: but i dont know which solution the sequence converges to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $f$ is bounded ($|f(x)| \le b$ on $\mathbb{R}$, say) the mean value theorem shows that each $u_n$ is Lipschitz-continuous with the same Lipschitz constant $b$. Thus $S:=\{u_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an equicontinuous set in
$C([0,1])$, and as $\{u_n(0):n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$
the set $S$ is bounded in $C([0,1])$. To see this, just note that
$$
|u_n(t)| \le |u_n(t)-u_n(0)| + |u_n(0)|\le bt+ |u_n(0)| \le b+ |u_n(0)|
$$
for $t \in [0,1]$. Now, from Arcela-Ascoli's theorem we get that there is a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ from  $(u_{n})$ which is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ to a function $v$, say. Now $(f(u_{n_k}))$ is uniformly convergent to $f(v)$. Next, from
$$
u_{n_k}(t)=u_{n_k}(0)+\int_0^t f(u_{n_k}(\tau)) d\tau \quad (t \in [0,1])
$$
we get (as $k \to \infty$)
$$
v(t)=v(0)+\int_0^t f(v(\tau)) d\tau \quad (t \in [0,1]).
$$
The integrand $f(v)$ is continuous, hence $v$ is differentiable and
$v'(t)=f(v(t))$ on $[0,1]$.

Remark: Under the assumtions on $f$ IVPs are not uniquely solvable, in general.